# Git: how to add all files in a folder recursively

Tags: git

I have a git folder and inside it there are two inner folders (they are called 'BackEnd' and 'FrontEnd').

When I do "git add ." and then "git status" I get:

> Changes to be committed:   (use "git rm --cached ..." to
>   unstage)
>
> ```
>     new file:   BackEnd
>     new file:   FrontEnd
> ```

The folders BackEnd and FrontEnd are added as files. I want that all files under these folders will be added recursively, meaning all of the files that are contained in these folders will be added.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure those folders don't have a `.git` subfolder of their own.

That would make them **nested git repo**, which means Git would only add them as **gitlink** (special entry in the parent repo index).

If you don't care about the history of those 2 nested repo, you could simply remove the `.git` folders, and try again:

```
git rm --cached -f BackEnd # no trailing slash
git add BackEnd
```

Comment: They had a .git subfolder but I deleted it.

Comment: @CrazySynthax I have edited the answer for you to add again the folder.

Comment: It seems to work. But one correction: "git rm --cached -f BackEnd" (-f has to be added)

Comment: @CrazySynthax OK, I have edited the answer accordingly.